# Local variable (in a function) to global (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four `<button>` tags, I need that when I click on the button tag, jQuery add the class `Active`.

This is the code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var btnActive;
    $(".cont-btn button:nth-of-type(1)").click(function () {
        btnActive = 1;
    });
    $(".cont-btn button:nth-of-type(" + btnActive + ")").click(function () {
        for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            if (i === btnActive) {
                $(".cont-btn button:nth-of-type(" + btnActive + ")").addClass("active");
            } else {
                $(".cont-btn button:nth-of-type(" + i + ")").removeClass("active");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Sorry for my English

PD. I get this error in the console `at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (proyectos.html:97)`

Comment: `I get this error in the console` That's the *origin* of the error, but not the actual error

Comment: When you create the second click event `btnActive` is undefined making the selector invalid.

Comment: This is the error line `$(".cont-btn button:nth-of-type(" + btnActive + ")").click(function () {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to handle this. When you click the button remove the buttons of interest then add it to the element you clicked:

```
$(".cont-btn").click(function () {
  $(".cont-btn").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qwy5u94t/)

Comment: Thank you very very very much, im a retard :facepalm:

Answer (score 0):

You are making it more complicated than it needs to be.

The following should do what you need assuming that `<button>` is inside `class="cont-btn"`

```
var $buttons = $(".cont-btn button").click(function () {
  $buttons.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".cont-btn button:nth-of-type(" + btnActive + ")")` this code is executed only once.

Your code may be like this

```
$('.cont-btn button:eq(0)').addClass('active');
$('.cont-btn button').click(function() {
    $('.cont-btn button').removeClass('active');  
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

P.s. I guess that you misunderstood how event handlers work. I would recommend you to read more on this topic. Execution flow in JS isn't easy to grasp.